# WordPress offset posts on home page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to offset the my homepage posts by 5.  I have a widget at the top that shows the first 5 already.

I use this in my functions.php to get the offset. and it works.  the problem is the widget doesn't print out posts from the beginning anymore.  All code below

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'myprefix_query_offset', 1);

function myprefix_query_offset(&$query) {

    //Before anything else, make sure this is the right query...
    if (!$query->is_home()) {
        return;
    }

    //First, define your desired offset...
    $offset = 5;

    //Next, determine how many posts per page you want (we'll use WordPress's settings)
    $ppp = get_option('posts_per_page');

    //Next, detect and handle pagination...
    if ($query->is_paged) {

        //Manually determine page query offset (offset + current page (minus one) x posts per page)
        $page_offset = $offset + ( ($query->query_vars['paged'] - 1) * $ppp );

        //Apply adjust page offset
        $query->set('offset', $page_offset);
    } else {

        //This is the first page. Just use the offset...
        $query->set('offset', $offset);
    }
}
```

The widget uses this, and when it does, it hands back the first 5 of the offset data set. and it's using the `get_featured_post` variable.

```
$get_featured_posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
        )
);
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue in the code is that it's not applying to the right query.

```
 add_action('pre_get_posts', 'myprefix_query_offset', 1);

function myprefix_query_offset(&$query) {

//Before anything else, make sure this is the right query...
if (!in_the_loop () || !is_main_query ()) {
    return;
}

//First, define your desired offset...
$offset = 5;

//Next, determine how many posts per page you want (we'll use WordPress's settings)
$ppp = get_option('posts_per_page');

//Next, detect and handle pagination...
if ($query->is_paged) {

    //Manually determine page query offset (offset + current page (minus one) x posts per page)
    $page_offset = $offset + ( ($query->query_vars['paged'] - 1) * $ppp );

    //Apply adjust page offset
    $query->set('offset', $page_offset);
} else {

    //This is the first page. Just use the offset...
    $query->set('offset', $offset);
}
}
```

can you try the code above and let me know if that work.

Thanks